# Why am I able to get rid of seg. fault if I put printf()?

Tags: c

my program has some list handling functions, everything worked fine until I added the reverseLinkedList function. I observed there was a seg. fault error, later on I figured out by adding a printf() "solve" the error, but I am not sure why.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
NODE *list_B;
void functionA();

int main ( )
{
..


   functionA();
   printf("O.o\n");// <=== if I add this line, the seg. fault is gone. Without it, I got the error
   printSummary(); //this is just printing out whatever is in list_B
}
void functionA()
{
   list_B = reverseLinkedList(list_B);
}

NODE* reverseLinkedList(NODE *head) //this is implemented in other head file.
{
    NODE *current = NULL;
    NODE *temp;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        temp->next = current;
        current = temp;
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. Show the implementation of the function `printSummary()`.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you pasted above - it's somewhere else - in printSummary or in your insert code.

Comment: You haven't initialilzed `list_B`... ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `printf` changes the values on the stack. If the functions after the `printf` do not initialize their local variables properly, this results in different behaviour including the `printf()` or not.

You seem to be comparing `stock_name` before it is set (with `malloc()`). Is that a global variable?

Answer (score 6):

You've figured out that `printf()` doesn't actually solve the problem in your code, it just masks the problem so you don't get a segmentation fault.

The segmentation fault is a *good* thing, because it helps you find the error in your code.  When you add `printf()`, the error is still there but the segmentation fault is gone... so it's harder to find the error.

Memory errors in C programs can result in very strange behavior.  Basically, anything can happen if your program has a memory error, and in this particular case what actually happens depends on whether that `printf()` call gets executed.  It would probably take a bit of sleuthing to figure out exactly what is going on here, but it is possible (for example) that some of your code depends on uninitialized memory, and `printf()` leaves behind some values in that memory that cause your other code to proceed harmlessly.

There are a number of different tools you can use to diagnose these problems.

1. Since your code gets a segmentation fault, you can hook up a debugger and see where the crash is.  The incorrect code might crash, or the crash might happen long after the incorrect code has executed.
2. Valgrind will often tell you which parts of your program rely on uninitialized values, which are a common source of this kind of crash.
3. Mudflap (compile with `gcc -fmudflap`) will also find some of these errors.  Mudflap and Valgrind have a lot of overlap, but sometimes one of them will find an error that the other one doesn't.